# merge columns in 2 text files properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, merge

I have 2 text files.

The first has data:

```
LA_3_45 test 1
LA_3_45 test 2
LA_3_45 test 3
..
```

The Next has Numbers:

```
1.34
2.53
-0.54
...
```

I want to combine them column-wise:

```
LA_3_45 test 1 1.34
LA_3_45 test 2 2.53
LA_3_45 test 3 -0.54
```

However, on using the `paste` command in Ubuntu I get the output with each element on a different line.

How do I get the right output?

Comment: There is no reason that `paste` wouldn't work. Please show us the command you use and the result.

Comment: paste file1.txt file2.txt > outfl.txt 

 I am getting the output on separate lines, the paste function is working though

Comment: Side note: if you want space to be the separator then you need `paste -d ' '`. It's tab by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your problem: You are using Windows files on Linux.

Windows text files terminate by carriage-return+line-feed,
while Linux text files terminate with only line-feed.

Therefore `paste` uses only the line-feed as end-of-line, thus conserving
the carriage-return. The paste result then seems to be in two lines
whenever that you display it.

To convert the end-of-line of Windows text files to that of Linux,
you may install and use
[dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix).
Once converted, the `paste` result will be correct for Linux.